# MySQL Select If Table Exists

Tags: mysql, case, information-schema

I need to run a count query on a table but only if that table exists,

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASENAME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'testtable') < 1 THEN '0' 
ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testtable) END;
```

The above query should return 0 if the table doesn't exist, but if it does it should get the count.

This returns an error saying "testtable" doesn't exist, we know it doesn't exist as the information_schema count returns 0.

Is this possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
       SET @val := CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASENAME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'testtable')
           WHEN 0 THEN 0
           ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASENAME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'testtable')

END;
        SELECT @val;
```

It will return 0, if there is no such table and if such table exists , it will return the count, it may be better if you take it into function.

Comment: you were kind of right but the query was still wrong, i've made an edit to your post once accepted i'll set as the answer.

Comment: oh yes, sorry forgot to add database name.

Comment: @Neo I've rolled back the edit. Although I'm sure it was right, edits that change code in that manner should be done by the creator of the post rather than by someone else; lest the meaning of the answer be changed beyond what the answerer originally intended.

Comment: This does not return the row-count of the table if exists. The question was how to get the row-count of `testtable` only if the table exists, without letting the SQL-statement throwing an error?