# How to tell if CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS created table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

The SQL query `CREATE TABLE mytable IF NOT EXISTS` returns true (in my PHP app) if the query ran correctly, but not if the table was actually created.

How can I tell if the table was created **without** running another query? I don't want to run double the amount of queries every single time my app runs.

Comment: @Furhad "Give your code"? What code would I possibly need to give?

Comment: As far as I know, DDL queries do not return anything. They may trigger a warning or error. Can you please provide more context?

Comment: @Glavić My question is to check without running another query. That answer says to use another query.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` returns `true` if the query ran, not if it actually worked. I've tagged the question with `php`, but it should apply to any language.

Comment: @Jazza: your original question was also "if not, what query do you advise"...

Comment: "More context" means "what are your reasons?"

Comment: where is the table structure. how can create a table without table structure

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738909/mysql-select-if-table-exists/18740546#18740546

Comment: If MySQL can't create the table it will return an error. Since you're using the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause the only reason MySQL will not return an error and not create a table is if the table already exists. If you want to know that you'll need to check for its existence before you attempt to create it. I don't really understand the purpose of your question.

Comment: In some applications you may want to automatically create a database table such as the very first time you run the app. Who wants to manually create tables every time you deploy?

Comment: @Glavić True. I removed that secondary question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Jazza - Alright, the `returns true` part refers to some undisclosed PHP code but I guess it isn't relevant: your question is how to perform two tasks with a single query. You'll possibly need to write a function.

Comment: (continued) Also I want to insert some default rows when I create my tables, such as a root user in a user table.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Indeed. The language shouldn't matter. I'm using PHP (I tagged the question with it) but it should apply to any language that can use SQL.

Comment: I reckon this question better be closed, only to stop all the pointless answers.

Comment: I was going to mark one of the answers as the solution, but they appeared to have deleted it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_name` (
`table field defination`
) ENGINE = `engine_name`
```