# MySQL query to check whether a table is in the database or not

Tags: mysql

I want to check whether a table is in the database or not. So what is the MySQL query to check whether a table is in the database or not ?

Comment: possible dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738909/mysql-select-if-table-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try with **database_name and table_name** also..

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
AND table_name = 'table_name'
```

**will return you 1 if exists else 0**

Comment: This is a better idea. I have one doubt too. What is "information_schema.tables" ?

Comment: **information_schema** is a database created my mysql it self to keep the information about the other database and tables.    and **tables** is a table inside **information_schema** which keeps the information about the tables..

Comment: I used that code like this :  preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema=mysql and table_name=addstudent");  Where will be the returning value get stored ?

Comment: its statement.. its not the execution of query.. you just prepared the statement .. next you need to execute the query.. then only it will return the value.. it will behave as normal table result..

Comment: Ok. I executed it using "preparedStatement.executeQuery();". Where will be the returning value gets stored ?

Comment: you have to take the result of ResultSet in Java.. atully **.executeQuery()** return you the resultSet. **ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();**  and then try **rs.next();** and **int exist = rs.getInt(1);** now if exist=1 mean table exists

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MyDataBase'
```

Comment: Could you explain what "information_schema.TABLES" and  "TABLE SCHEMA" are ?

Comment: infomation_schema is the master database, and tables is a table containing a list of all tables. table_schema is the database you are interested in.. ie: your own database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)  FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='dbname' and table_name='tblname'
```