# MySQL Select row-count if table exists

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the row-count from a table, but only if it exists. (In one SQL-statement.)

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738909/mysql-select-if-table-exists) question, the answer does not return the row-count from the table if it exists. How can this be done without MySQL throwing the error 'Table does not exist'??

My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN
        ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE `table_schema` = DATABASE() AND `table_name` = 'testTbl') > 0 )
    THEN
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `testTbl`)
    ELSE
        (SELECT 0)
    END;
```

EDIT: The `WHEN`-part returns the right value (0 if the table doesn't exist, and 1 if it does).
The real problem is that the entire SQL is not returning/selecting '0', when the tabel doesn't exist, but instead returns an error. (Because the non-existing table is mentioned in the `THEN`-clause, thereby defeating the whole purpose of previously checking if it exist. In other words, it can't ignore the `COUNT`-statement in the `THEN`-clause when the table doesn't exist.)

This is a problem, because I want the returned value to be an integer (or numeric value).

Comment: @Phillip, I would love to know how you've ended up needing to do this, it has a slight aroma of code smell to it.

Comment: @Rob, I would normally do this with 2 separate queries, but for this instance I need it to be in one. So, that is the real problem haha

Comment: regardless of how many queries, why are you doing this at all?

Comment: As part of pre-processing data for displaying in a chart, I need the row-count of a table (or 0 if not existing) as a single query for PHP to execute and retrieve (in Wordpress) with a `get_var()` call

Comment: I found a solution, I think :)

Comment: @Philip : what was the solution that you found ?

Comment: @varun_arora I put my found solution below as the accepted answer. It is not ideal, but fitted the project I was working on at the time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The closest solution I found to my problem is getting the `table_rows` column from the `information_schema` table (if the table exists):

```
SELECT IF(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (DATABASE()) AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'tokens_331698')>0,
        (SELECT `TABLE_ROWS` as `x` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (DATABASE()) AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'tokens_331698'),
        0
)
```

The only problem with this, is that I'm not sure how accurate this row-count value is. (Anyone?)

Comment: Depending on the table engine it can be anything from wildly inaccurate to a reasonable estimate. InnoDB is particularly unreliable.

Comment: According to MySQL's documentation, only InnoDB has this problem (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html). Or is this the same with MyISAM tables?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking around and found this thread. I wanted to count the number of rows in a table if it exists, or return `-1` if the table doesn't exist.
Replace `[database_name]` and `[table_name]` by your own values.

```
SELECT MAX(TABLE_ROWS) AS TABLE_ROWS 
       FROM information_schema.tables 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '[database_name]' 
            AND TABLE_NAME = '[table_name]'
```

This query returns a column `TABLE_ROWS` with a unique row containing the number of rows of `[table_name]` if table exists or `NULL` if `[table_name]` doesn't exist.

If I want to return `-1` instead of `NULL` if the table does not exist, I use the following query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(TABLE_ROWS), -1) AS TABLE_ROWS 
       FROM information_schema.tables 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '[database_name]' 
            AND TABLE_NAME = '[table_name]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the tale exist before the query:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE testTbl;
```

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '[database name]' 
AND table_name = '[table name]';
```

If you get any result from the query than the table exist!

Comment: I tried: `IF( EXISTS( SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE `table_schema` = DATABASE() AND `table_name` = 'testTbl' ) )
BEGIN
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `testTbl`)
END`, but it doesn't work..

Comment: `IF( EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM testTbl ) )
BEGIN
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testTbl)
END` doesn't work either I'm affraid. Is gives an syntax error.

Comment: As stated in my question the problem is not that I can't check if the table exists, but that I want to return the row-count of that table (if it exists) or '0' if it doesn't

Comment: You can find here how to do it: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/check-if-mysql-table-exists/

Comment: I understand how to check if the table exists :) That is not the problem