# MYSQL Using IF before select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i have a MSSQL query like this :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TImportFlex') 
BEGIN
    SELECT count(1) val
    FROM TImportFlex
    INNER JOIN TPersonal b ON TImportFlex.pers_id = b.pers_id
END
ELSE SELECT 0 VAL
```

i tried to use this query in MYSQL but it seems i cannot execute it in MYSQL..

Can someone tell me why this query is not available in MYSQL?

Comment: What errors/issues are you getting while trying to execute it in MySQL?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738909/mysql-select-if-table-exists

Comment: It is available but in stored programs only.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir the error is SQL error (1064)